# Why app's icon shows blank in iCloud settings?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, bundle, icloud

I'm currently adding iCloud support for my app, but i noticed that in the iCloud -> manage storage settings my app's icon is missing. I've added the Icon-Small.png/Icon-Small-50.png plus their @2x versions in the xcode project in the "Resources" folder, then added their names in Info.plist but it still shows white.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please note that the app is not live yet on the App Store. Does it affect the iCloud icon?

Comment: I would like to know that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you show up in Settings, a little like registering your device for push notifications, there's some caching happening. You should try resetting all settings and installing fresh. Also if it's a physical device, not the simulator, try to delete the app, set the date forward by over a day, install fresh, and it should bypass that cache.

Answer (score 1):

Did you build the app, compile it, and added the icon very later on? This is usually a caché issue. The best way to go around this is to uninstall the app from your device and do a clean build.